# Angular controller extending

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I was following a tutorial found on that website: http://digital-drive.com/?p=188 which let's me use an `extend` approach to make it able to create parent/child controllers. Everything seems to work just fine, except one thing - instance methods and properties. My code is organized with [this approach](http://abhisheksarka.github.io/structuring-angular-with-rails/) and it more or less looks like that:

#### test_mixin.coffee

```
(->
  app = angular.module("myApp.mixins")
  app.controller "myApp.mixins.TestMixin", [
    "$scope"
    ($scope) ->

      _this = this

      @notWorkingVar    = "It's not working"
      $scope.workingVar = "It's working!"
  ]
)
```

#### controller.coffee

```
(->
  app = angular.module("myApp.components.MyComponent")
  app.controller "myApp.components.MyComponent.Controller", [
    "$scope"
    "$controller"
    ($scope, $controller) ->

      _this = this

      # Extends
      angular.extend this, $controller('myApp.mixins.TestMixin', {
        $scope: $scope })

      # Not working examples:
      console.log _this.notWorkingVar
      console.log this.notWorkingVar
      console.log @notWorkingVar

      # Working example:
      console.log $scope.workingVar
  ]
)
```

Basically, stuff attached to `$scope` works just fine. But the rest fails. Have someone any idea on what is wrong in here and how can i fix that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Placing your code into a JSFiddle as standard JavaScript I was not able to reproduce your issue, and the values set on TestMixin were displaying in 'myApp.components.MyComponent.Controller' when it ran.

See example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/j6arq9z5/3/

```
var app = angular.module("myApp.mixins", []);

app.controller("myApp.mixins.TestMixin", function($scope) {
      _this = this

      this.notWorkingVar    = "It's not working"
      $scope.workingVar = "It's working!"
});

  app.controller("myApp.components.MyComponent.Controller", function($scope, $controller) {
      _this = this

      angular.extend(this, $controller('myApp.mixins.TestMixin', {
        $scope: $scope }));

      console.log(_this.notWorkingVar);
      console.log(this.notWorkingVar);

      console.log($scope.workingVar);
  });
```